# Is there a way to change explorer settings in java?

Tags: java, windows

I am making something like a custom desktop app with it's own "app bar" (similar to RocketDock) and a lot of customizations to windows. The last thing I need is to make some changes to explorer settings. I need to set new wallpaper, put the windows bar to the top and show it only when mouse is on it and lastly I need to hide desktop icons. Is it possible to do it in java ? If yes, can you tell me how ? I am willing to accept any solution, even if it might include something like making few more apps that are not written in java but can be executed with java program.

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve. (The macbook bar is photoshopped because my custom bar is not finished yet. As you can see I am referring to "explorer.exe" which is also a desktop for windows. The corner button is used to hide/show desktop icons and the windows bar is hidden in the top of the screen. Also the background is changed

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to [Windows File Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer)? Perhaps you could post an image of how you want _explorer_ to look (with your new wallpaper).

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve. (The macbook bar is photoshopped because my custom bar is not finished yet. https://i.imgur.com/0ydgj0x.jpg as you can see I am refering to "explorer.exe" which is also a desktop for windows. The corner button is used to hide/show desktop icons and the windows bar is hidden in the top of the screen. Also the background is changed

Comment: OK. I think I understand what you are trying to do but I don't think I fully understand how you are trying to do it. If it were me, I would write a java GUI app that uses either _Swing_ or JavaFX and have the main application window take up the entire screen. Is that what you are doing? Or do you want your java code to modify the settings of the host operating system, i.e. Windows in your case.

Comment: Writing an app that would take up the entire screen would be easier but it would take longer. Therefor I want to change just a few Windows settings so my app would look as I intended and would be also light weight compared to making full screen app. I found java library called JNA that provides some functionality that I want (such as changing wallpaper) but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Join me in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218979/abra-and-user204855)